# Handle touch event on Apple - Highcharts

Tags: jquery, ios, highcharts

I have a problem in iOS on touch event with Highcharts Labels.

I have enabled click on labels also in highcharts by using below code:

```
point : {
    events : {
        click : function() {
            var resultMatch = $.inArray(this.x,innerIndex);
            var selectedSliceColor = 
            mainPieDataSeries[this.x].graphic.attr('fill');
            handleCategorySelection(this.x, this.y,this.name, 
                                    selectedSliceColor);
        },
        mouseOver : function() {
                    /* functions*/
        }
    }
}
```

This click event works very well on laptop and other devices except Apple iPad. For make this event to work, i have to

> Long press the label and then click is fired.

Is there any idea we can handle this event in Highcharts as in jQuery i know
we have to go with binding touchstart event.

```
.bind(touchstart)
```

But how to handle for Highcharts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [custom-events](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events) extension and catch `"touchstart"` and `"touchend"` events.

Comment: should i remove click and use touchstart or same methods shall be copied to touchstart

Comment: any example will do pl